# IList<HttpPostedFileBase> is null after post when using FIleUpload handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to pass a IList of HttpPostedFileBase objects and a "Post" object to an Action.  I receive the Post object just fine but my IList is always empty.

See code below...

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Post post, IList<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var attachmentCounter = attachments.Count;

        post.SubmissionDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        db.Posts.AddObject(post);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { category = post.Category });
    }

    return View(post);
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Posts", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Post</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Category)

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Author)

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label>Photo Attachments:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <span style="color:#666; font-size:12px; font-weight:normal;">(Optional)</span>
            </label>

        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Raw(FileUpload.GetHtml(
            name: "attachments",
            initialNumberOfFiles: 1,
            allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: true,
            includeFormTag: false,
            addText: "Add another photo...",
            uploadText: "").ToString().Replace("<input value\"\" type=\"submit\" />", ""))
        </div>

        <br />

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="createButton" style="font-weight:normal;" /> | 
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { category = Model.Category }, null)
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to reproduce your issue, but in my environment all is working. But anyway check once again that your **name** property in FileUpload exactly the same as second parameter property in controller (even better copypaste it). The Second thing you need to check is the size of file you uploading to the server. If it's bigger then request size allowed in your web config, values will be null.

Also you could check in your method value of `Request.Files` if it's empty that will means that your file do not even uploading to server. If file will be available, you could get it from there.

Comment: I added in the maxRequestLength to the web config but still nothing.  I have a break point set at the IList count method within the controller and the IList of HttpPostedFileBase objects is always empty.

Comment: What's about Request.Files value?